# Ruby zip cannot open docx file

Tags: ruby, docx, rubyzip

What I'm doing is trying to open a blank docx with rubyzip and i keep getting the error:

```
Zip::Error: File /b;a/bla/bla/existing_file.docx not found
```

Is there a rule in rubyzip that prevents opening empty zipfiles?

Answer (score 0):

`rubyzip` only supports compressing existing files. What you can do is to create an empty file using `touch`, then zip it.

```
require "fileutils"
FileUtils.touch '/b;a/bla/bla/existing_file.docx'
```